# git diff-filter reports unchanged smudge/cleaned files

Tags: git, gitattributes

for a repo with smudge/clean filters, a diff command like so

> git diff master --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR

keeps reporting all my (unchanged) smudged files.

Answer (score 0):

use the `--cached` flag, to ignore local edits.

> git diff master **--cached** --diff-filter=ACMR